Selenium Xpath to select text between span
I am trying to select the HITT element shown below.
<span class="classname"> HITT </span>

So I tied the following Xpath expression:
//span[@class="classname" and text()="HITT"] 

Which does not work/find the element in question. The first part will work, i.e.
//span[@class="classname"] 

This finds all the elements where starting with . But when I add the "and text()" portion it doesn't work.
Please let me know what mistake I'm making here. Thanks!


<span class="classname"> HITT </span>

If you notice, HITT has a trailing and leading whitespace. Hence text()="HITT" won't work.
Try this:
//span[@class="classname" and contains(text(),"HITT")] 


Awesome, that works!
Another question just out of curiosity, I did notice the trailing/leading whitespace, one of the things I tried was //span[@class="classname" and text()=" HITT "]  (copied the text directly from the HTML, given how many different spaces there are in utf-8) but this didn't work. Any idea why?

Ideally what you tried should have worked. In the past, I have constructed XPath expression without using contains() function but giving whitespace just like what you tried, and it has worked for me. Not really sure why it didn't work for you. One thing I can think of is while the HTML renders may be it is adding more whitespaces. Again am not too sure, sorry.
